# NumPy mgrid into tuples

Tags: numpy

How the result can be obtained from given NumPy array (xx and yy)?

```
>>> xx, yy = np.mgrid[0:2, 5:7]
>>> xx
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1]])
>>> yy
array([[5, 6],
       [5, 6]])
>>> result = [(0,5), (1,5), (1,6), (0,6)]
>>> result
[(0, 5), (1, 5), (1, 6), (0, 6)]
>>>
```

Comment: Could you change the numbers so it is clear which ones come from `xx` and which from `yy`?

Comment: Actually, my xx and yy are larger than it; but the result should be list of lists in the order as shown in the question. (The question is only for one list)

Comment: Are you sure you want the `xx` values in the [0,1,1,0] order?  That can't be done with reshaping.  It will require some sort of advanced indexing.

Comment: But it should work when the xx and yy larger the size shown in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in your example requires some fancy indexing of `xx`.  I had to reverse the order of the 2nd column.

```
In [243]: np.array([np.array([xx[:,0], xx[::-1,1]]).flatten(), yy.T.flatten()]).T.tolist()
Out[243]: [[0, 5], [1, 5], [1, 6], [0, 6]]
```

If the order isn't so important, then we can treat `xx` just like `yy`:

```
In [256]: xx, yy = np.mgrid[0:3, 5:8]

In [257]: np.array([xx.T.flatten(),yy.T.flatten()]).T.tolist()
Out[257]: [[0, 5], [1, 5], [2, 5], [0, 6], [1, 6], [2, 6], [0, 7], [1, 7], [2, 7]]

In [258]: np.array([xx.flatten(),yy.flatten()]).T.tolist()
Out[258]: [[0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7]]

In [264]: np.array([xx,yy]).reshape(2,-1).T.tolist()
Out[264]: [[0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7]]

In [272]: np.dstack([xx,yy]).reshape(-1,2).tolist()
Out[272]: [[0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7]]

In [302]: list(np.broadcast(*np.ogrid[0:3,5:8]))
Out[302]: [(0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7)]
```

Comment: Just stumbled over this. Wanted to add that you could also use list(zip(xx.T.flatten(),yy.T.flatten()))